# Where can I find land utilisation data

Tags: geospatial, land

I need to find a database describing the land use for a given latitude and longitude. Examples of land use types: farming lands, urban areas etc.

Comment: Worldwide? Free? What resolution? Please [read this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) and [edit] this into a better question.

Comment: https://nationalmap.gov/small_scale/mld/ldco100.html may or may not be helpful

Answer (score 1):

https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov has various types of data worldwide. One of the categories is land cover. Use the interactive map tool to check if the data you want is available for your area of interest.